# Regex to skip all occurences of ")" but the last one in a string

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a way to validate a string that contains parenthesees so that the expression ignores all but the last one?

The regex expression is like this: `(?<function>^(?!\/_).[A-Za-z_]*)\((?<args>[^\)]+\))`, and the string has the following format:

```
web_convert_param("sEV_4_URL2",
                  "SourceString={sEV_4}",
                  "SourceEncoding=HTML",
                  "TargetEncoding=URL",
                  "veh_sym_sel=EXT%20CAB%20(8CYL%204x2)",
                   LAST);
```

If run this in the [Regex Tester](http://regexhero.net/tester/) it stops at the next two the last closing parent. Is this possible in this context?

The C# code that runs this looks like this:

```
try 
{ 
    var autoRemove = new ArrayList(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AutoRemoveFunctions"].Split(',')); 
    baseFileData = ScriptProperties.ScriptText; 
    var matches = regEx_SBR.Matches(baseFileData); 
    foreach (Match match in matches) 
    { 
       var functionName = match.Groups["function"].Value.Trim(); 
       if (autoRemove.Contains(functionName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(functionName)) continue; 
       var args = match.Groups["args"].Value; 
       args = match.Groups["args"].Value.Replace("\"", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""); 
       var arguments = args.Split(','); 
       _scriptFunction = new BaseScriptFunction(); 
       ParseFunction(match.Groups["function"].Value.Trim(), arguments, match.Value.Trim()); 
       if (_scriptFunction.IsNamedTransaction) 
       { 
           _scriptFunction.TransactionName = string.Format("{0}{1}",transactionPrefix, _scriptFunction.TransactionName);  
       } 
       ScriptFunctions.Add(_scriptFunction); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead use `[\s\S]` and use `\);` for the conclusion of the regex? Something like this:

```
(?<function>^(?!\/_).[A-Za-z_]*)\((?<args>[\s\S]+?)\);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/eE6mU4)

`[\s\S]` matches any character. You can use `.` instead but with the `(?s)` flag too.

---

Maybe you could try this for a better regex without the final semicolon:

```
(?<function>^(?!\/_).[A-Za-z_]*)\((?<args>(?:"[^"]+"|[^\)"]+)+)\)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/wO3kM4).

This works if you don't have any `"` within the argument strings themselves (escaped or not). If you can have escaped `"`, then the regex will have to be longer...

```
(?<function>^(?!\/_).[A-Za-z_]*)\((?<args>(?:"(?:\\.|[^"\\]+)+"|[^\)"]+)+)\)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/jG3kD2)

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply. It turns out there is little more to this. The semicolor at the end needs to ne exluded.

Comment: Two questions then: 1. What language are you using? 2. Are there more functions in the same string/file you're applying the regex against?

Comment: The script is in C, and I just inadvertantly mentioned that I've done little regex in the past, and got succkered into this - way over my head. I'm basically releying thist to the developer. Turns out your suggestions work on the given example but broke something else. I may have to edit my post to include more details.

Comment: @Risho Okay, could you try one of the two regexes I added to my answer? The last one is longer, but I guess more foolproof.

Comment: Your original suggestion worked except that it somehow the process added an second semicolon to the output. I just edited my post to include the C# code that runs the regex.

Comment: @Risho I can't say I'm too C# savvy ^^; I don't recognise a lot of the functions you're using, so I might be misinterpreting some lines... But the first regex does depend on the ending semicolon. The next two regexes I suggested don't. Could you perhaps try those out?

Comment: So the two regexes you've added brake at the quotation marks.

Comment: @Risho Yup, and they ignore everything inside that isn't a quote and then continue in the match.